# Android app long-click: works in from Android Studio, not otherwise

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

This is a really bizarre one.... I've written a very simple Android shopping-list app which uses a `RecyclerView`. I want the user to long-click on an item to select it for deletion, etc. The long-click works fine when I run the app from Android Studio, both on the emulator and via USB on a real device; it doesn't work when the app is installed independently.

By "doesn't work", I mean that the app simply doesn't respond to a long-click. It doesn't crash or anything; just nothing happens. Strangely, a short-click on the same `RecyclerView`, using the same mechanism (of which further below), works fine.

Here's what I've tried, in which the long-click **doesn't** work:

- Signed release build, uploaded to Play Store and installed from there.
- Signed release build, APK transferred to phone via USB and installed by clicking on it.
- Debug build, APK transferred to phone via USB and installed by clicking on it.

I've also commented out everything from the release build type in `build.gradle`, so (in theory anyway) the release build should be the same as the debug one, but no difference:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        // minifyEnabled false
        // proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        // signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
```

What am I missing, or what am I doing wrong?

#### How it's supposed to work

My `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` implementation responds to short- and long-clicks, and I'm using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to transmit events to the fragment hosting the `RecyclerView`, which handles them.

```
class ShoppingListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
  //....
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ShoppingListViewHolder holder, final int position)
{
    // ....

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // This always gets called.
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new ItemClickEvent(item, holder.getAdapterPosition()));
        }
    });

    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v)
        {
            // This doesn't get called when the app is not run from Android Studio.
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new ItemLongClickEvent(item, holder.getAdapterPosition()));
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the method in the hosting fragment which responds to the events posted to `Eventbus`:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
void onItemLongClick(ShoppingListAdapter.ItemLongClickEvent event)
{
    // This doesn't get called when the app is not run from Android Studio.
}
```

As I said above, this all works fine when the app is launched directly from Android Studio, both on the emulator and on a real phone; but once the app is installed independently of Studio, the long-click no longer responds.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it looks like a problem with the version of your build tools or the recycle view versions. wich versions are you using?

Comment: @Catluc Build tools are version 25.0.2, RecyclerView uses version 25.1.1. For what it's worth my minSdkVersion is 21 and targetSdkVersion is 25.